# Call mapActions method from components script area

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I know that I can call a mapActions method from the template of a component with only typing in the functions name.
But how can I call a mapActions method from inside the script tag of a component.

```
axios.put('api/presenter/'+presenterId, presenter).then(function(res) {
                if(res.data !== true) {
                    // something went wrong
                    console.error(res.data)
                } else {
                    // here I want to call the mapActions method
                    callMethodHere(res.data)
                    alert('edited') // replace later
                }
          }).catch(function(err) {
              console.error(err)
          })
```

But callMethodHere will be undefined..

My vuex file

```
addSpeaker(state, speaker) {
    state.allSpeaker = [...state.allSpeaker, speaker]
}

addSpeaker({commit}, speaker) {
    commit('addSpeaker', speaker)
}
```

Here is my component where I call the vue store property:

```
<ul>
        <li v-for="presenter in allSpeaker" :key="presenter.id">
            {{presenter.name}} <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="edit(presenter.id)">Edit</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

computed: {
        ...mapState({
            allSpeaker: state => state.allSpeaker
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `then` callback as an arrow function to be able to get access to `this` (component instance) then call that method using `this.callMethodHere(res.data)` :

```
axios.put('api/presenter/'+presenterId, presenter).then((res)=> {
                if(res.data !== true) {
                    // something went wrong
                    console.error(res.data)
                } else {
                    
                    this.callMethodHere(res.data)
                    alert('edited') // replace later
                }
          }).catch(function(err) {
              console.error(err)
          })
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But the state does not change. In the store folder I've got all right, a const action which commits to mutations. But the list I show in the template aboce does not refresh after I commit in the actions method. It refreshes after I press F5 only

Comment: you're welcome, that's a reactivity issue I think you could add use  `state.allSpeaker.push(speaker)` instead of `state.allSpeaker = [...state.allSpeaker, speaker]`

Comment: It still didn't work with the push method. I will add more details on my OP about my vue component

Comment: It's better to keep the original post and post another one with the new issue